# Netboot Debian (wheezy) from NFS v4

Tags: nfs, pxe-boot, netboot, nfs4, debian-wheezy

Is it possible to boot Debian Wheezy from NFS v4?

Bootwing with NFS v3 works just fine. NFS v4 not.

This is in my `/etc/exports`:

```
/nfs 192.168.100.0/24(ro,sync,insecure,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,fsid=0)
/nfs/root 192.168.100.0/24(ro,nohide,sync,insecure,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

`/nfs/root/www` contains the root of the webserver.

The commandline is:

```
rootfstype=nfs4 root=/dev/nfs4 nfsroot=192.168.100.1:/root/www
```

fails with 
`mount call failed - server replied: Permission denied.`

Mounting from the busybox in the initrd fails:

```
mount -t nfs4 192.168.100.1:/nfs/root/www /root
mounting .. failed: Invalid argument
```

Do I need to modify the initrd?

Comment: It's not a direct solution, but have you considered using iPXE?  You can boot off a webserver or iSCSI target.  You can chainload it, so you do not need to modify any NIC firmware, and so you can boot VMs from it too.  http://ipxe.org/

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to create a initrd with nfs4 mount utils in it.
Or maybe try this: http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/dracut.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.